# Replacing a line with two new lines

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting

I have a file named `abc.csv` which contains these 6 lines:

```
xxx,one
yyy,two
zzz,all
aaa,one
bbb,two
ccc,all
```

Now whenever `all` comes in a line that line should be replaced by both `one` and `two`, that is:

```
xxx,one
yyy,two
zzz,one
zzz,two
aaa,one 
bbb,two
ccc,one
ccc,two
```

Can someone help how to do this?

Comment: while read line
do
echo $line
        if [ "`echo $line | awk -F, '{print $2}'`" = "all" ]
        then
        echo "`echo $line | awk -F, '{print $1}`,one"
        echo "`echo $line | awk -F, '{print $1}`,two"
        fi
done < abc.csv

Almost Done - 90 %.. Now have to remove the line

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, '/all/ { print $1, "one"; print $1, "two"; next }1' foo.input
xxx,one
yyy,two
zzz,one
zzz,two
aaa,one
bbb,two
ccc,one
ccc,two
```

If you want to stick to a shell-only solution:

```
while read line; do
    if [[ "${line}" = *all* ]]; then
        echo "${line%,*},one"
        echo "${line%,*},two"
    else
        echo "${line}"
    fi
done < foo.input
```

Comment: Hi Adrian I am sorry.. there is no 'line 1,line 2,line3 and all' in file.. It starts directly with xxx,one .. second line ll be yyy,two..  just for explanation i wrote line 1,line 2,etc..

Comment: @user2686786 Ah, that makes sense...I changed my answer accordingly. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: while read line 
do 
echo $line 
if [ "echo $line | awk -F, '{print $2}'" = "all" ] 
then 
echo "echo $line | awk -F, '{print $1},one" 
echo "echo $line | awk -F, '{print $1},two" 
fi 
done < abc.csv

I tried this one .. but that line containg all is also displayed..
You have any idea how to remove that line

Comment: @user2686786 Your code cannot really work at all like that (e.g. missing `$()` for command substitution among other things), but I added a shell solution to my answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

In `sed`:

```
sed '/,all$/{ s/,all$/,one/p; s/,one$/,two/; }'
```

When the line matches `,all` at the end, first substitute `all` with `one` and print it; then substitute `one` with `two` and let the automatic print do the printing.